# Android Web View Don't showing My URL in Android 4.1

Tags: java, android, webview

I have created a web view but it is not showing my Link in Android 4.1-4.4 when I run the app. Does anyone know why?

Can you please help me how can I use a web view to showing my link for all devices.

my webView showing my URL in Android 5, 6, 7 and it works properly. but in below version [4.1- 4.4], my webView don't show. it waiting for loading page of the website.

its link is showing in my browser, but don't show in my app web view in Android 4.1 or 4.4(KitKat). in Android 5 and later it working properly.

Here is my code. This is where I load the web view and add a URL:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView myWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);

    String url = "seobaan.com";

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebView());

    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    myWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    myWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    myWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://" + url);

}

private class MyWebView extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        myWebView.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        handler.proceed();
    }
}
}
```

Here is the layout that I am inflating:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.samplewebview.MainActivity">
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/myWebView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </WebView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

in here is my API level:

```
    applicationId "com.seobaanapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
```

thank you for any response!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below attributes and check it

`settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);`

and also check the manifest 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`
and mobile internet connection.
Replace the url

```
String url="www.seobaan.com";
```

and check it.

Comment: don't show .it wait in loading page of the web site. it have permission .

Answer (score 0):

Check what is your API level. Is it also applicable to android 4.1 or 4.4 kitkat?

Comment: applicationId "com.seobaanapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

Comment: what is that error when installing in kitkat post it here

Comment: when app is running in android Jelly Bean and  KitKat, that url just showing loading page of the Web Site. but in Lollipop and later version after showing loading page, show the main page of the web site and worked properly.

Comment: it link is showing in device browser, just in webview don't show it in android 4.1 to 4.4 ! it have Internet Permission .

Comment: may be clear cache and clear data for that app and check again

Comment: mWebview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);  add this line and check